# How to find multiple patterns using Regex findall?

Tags: python, regex, string

My task is to get "li","ul" tags from a string and get count of them. 
 This is what I tried, it works but looking for better solution

The String

```
<ul><li>Regularly wash your hands for 20 seconds or use a hand sanitizer with at least 60 percent alcohol. Pay attention to hand hygiene, especially when you’ve been in a public place and after coughing, sneezing, or blowing your nose.</li>
<li>Practice <a href="https://www.answers.com/Q/What_is_social_distancing" rel="nofollow ugc">social distancing</a> by increasing the space between you and other people. That means staying home as much as you can, especially if you feel sick.</li>
<li>Disinfect frequently touched surfaces (like keyboards, doorknobs, and light switches) every day.</li>
<li>Cover coughs and sneezes with the inside of your elbow or a tissue. Throw the tissue away immediately and wash your hands.</li>,</ul>
```

---

Code:

```
liTag = re.findall('<li>',String)
ulTag = re.findall('<ul>',String)
count = len(liTag) + len(ulTag)
```

Comment: I think better solution would by using proper HTML parser, such as `BeautifulSoup`

Comment: Or, if you don't want to put up with BeautifuSoup's byzantine interface, pyquery. You don't want to parse HTML with regex.

Comment: you may `<ul class="...">` or something similar and then your regex is useless. Using `BeautifulSoup`, `lxml` or `pyquery` you could do this.

Comment: Now i have added the string please take a look. I dont think Beautiful soup is appropriate to use in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example `re` is good solution and you don't have to search other method.

Eventually you can write it as

```
tags = re.findall('<(li|ul)>', html)
print(len(tags))
```

But if you get more complex tags like `<ul class="...">` (or more complex) then `regex` will not work and better (and easier) is to use `lxml`, `BeautifulSoup` or other HTML parser.

**lxml:**

```
import lxml.html

html = '''<ul id="list">
<li class="first">Regularly wash your hands for 20 seconds or use a hand sanitizer with at least 60 percent alcohol. Pay attention to hand hygiene, especially when you’ve been in a public place and after coughing, sneezing, or blowing your nose.</li>
<li name="second">Practice <a href="https://www.answers.com/Q/What_is_social_distancing" rel="nofollow ugc">social distancing</a> by increasing the space between you and other people. That means staying home as much as you can, especially if you feel sick.</li>
<li style="color:red">Disinfect frequently touched surfaces (like keyboards, doorknobs, and light switches) every day.</li>
<li data="last">Cover coughs and sneezes with the inside of your elbow or a tissue. Throw the tissue away immediately and wash your hands.</li>
</ul>'''

soup = lxml.html.fromstring(html)

li_tags = soup.xpath('//li')
ul_tags = soup.xpath('//ul')
count = len(li_tags) + len(ul_tags)

print(count)
```

You can even try

```
tags = soup.xpath('//ul|//li')
print(len(tags))
```

**BeautifulSoup:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<ul id="list">
<li class="first">Regularly wash your hands for 20 seconds or use a hand sanitizer with at least 60 percent alcohol. Pay attention to hand hygiene, especially when you’ve been in a public place and after coughing, sneezing, or blowing your nose.</li>
<li name="second">Practice <a href="https://www.answers.com/Q/What_is_social_distancing" rel="nofollow ugc">social distancing</a> by increasing the space between you and other people. That means staying home as much as you can, especially if you feel sick.</li>
<li style="color:red">Disinfect frequently touched surfaces (like keyboards, doorknobs, and light switches) every day.</li>
<li data="last">Cover coughs and sneezes with the inside of your elbow or a tissue. Throw the tissue away immediately and wash your hands.</li>
</ul>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

li_tags = soup.find_all('li')
ul_tags = soup.find_all('ul')
count = len(li_tags) + len(ul_tags)

print(count)
```

You can even do

```
tags = soup.find_all(('ul', 'li'))
print(len(tags))
```

---

**EDIT:** In `html` in every tag `<ul>`, `<li>` I added extra information - `id`, `class`, `name`, `style`, `data` - and code still works without changes.

For `regex` it would need `'<(li|ul).*>'` or `'<(ul|li)'`. But for something more complex it would need even more complex changes.